# How to View Windows Scheduled Task History for all Tasks?

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks

I know that I can click on the history tab for a selected task to see the history of when the task executed, but I need to look through the history of all scheduled tasks, not just a particular one.

Is there a way to export or view all scheduled task history in a single list?